# Is it appropriate to add advice to my answer?

Tags: discussion

Sometimes, while answering a question a related but not directly-asked bit of advice might pop into my head.

For example, if a question were "How to I make my integer go up by one?"

```
int theIntegerThatRepresentsTheNumberOfStudents = 0;
theIntegerThatRepresentsTheNumberOfStudents + 1;
```

In addition to an answer I might suggest they rename it something more manageable like

```
int numStudents = 0;
numStudents++;
```

Is it inappropriate for me to add a small suggestion like that **after/as part of an actual answer** if it wasn't directly asked for in the question?

Comment: By the way, I'd call it `studentCount`. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3742650 https://stackoverflow.com/q/6358588 https://stackoverflow.com/q/548646

Comment: There's [codereview.se] for reviewing working code. You might alternatively suggest OP to have it reviewed there...

Comment: @AndrewT. but then you'll have users who appear to have a comment-feed-bot that triggers on links to Code Review come and tell you all the reasons why Code Review doesn't want any questions from here, or something like that.

Comment: In what language would the first example actually work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is perfectly acceptable.  I do this sort of thing all the time should the need arise.  Don't let it distract from the main point of the answer, though; we don't need to check someone's code style for the umpteenth time.